# Converse to Wronskian Condition ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u_1(x),\dots, u_n(x)$ be solutions to the $n$th order, linear, homogeneous differential equation $y^{(n)} + p_1(x)y^{(n-1)} + \dots + p_n(x)y = 0.$

Let $W := W[u_1, \dots, u_n]$ denote the Wronskian of these solutions.

If $W$ is equal to $0$ for any $x_0$, then we know by Abel's identity that $W$ is identically $0$.

Theorem: $W = 0 \implies u_1, \dots, u_n$ are linearly dependent.

This is the theorem I want to prove.

Exercise 25(b) section 4.1 of "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems," by Boyce, Diprima suggests:

Suppose $u_1, \dots, u_n$ are linearly independent. If $W(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0$, show there is a nonzero solution to the homogenous linear ODE above satisfying initial conditions $y(x_0) = y'(x_0) = \dots = y^{(n-1)}(x_0) = 0$, then the result follows from a contradiction of the uniqueness theorem, since $y = 0$ is also a solution.

Along this path, it seems that a good place to start is represent $W$ in terms of the cofactor expansion along the first row of $W$:

$W = u_1M_1 - u_2M_2 + \dots + (-1)^{(1 + n)}u_nM_n$. (Where $M_i$ is the determinant of the Wronskian matrix with first row and $i$th column removed).

Then let $u(x) = u_1(x)M_1(x_0) - u_2(x)M_2(x_0) + \dots + (-1)^{(1 + n)}u_n(x)M_n(x_0).$
$u(x_0) = 0$, and by linear independence of $u_1, \dots, u_n$, if the $M_i(x_0)$ are not identically $0$, and $u^\prime(x_0) = \dots = u^{(n - 1)}(x_0) = 0$, then this solves it.

I'm pretty stuck at this point. Not really sure if this is the right way to go about it or, if so, where to go next. A complete answer or any hints/advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n$ be solutions of the stated ODE. The Wronskian $W(x_0)$ is $0$ iff the Wronskian matrix is not invertible or, equivalently, the Wronskian matrix has a non-trivial null space. Equivalently, there is a non-zero vector with components $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ such that
$$
        a_1\left[\begin{array}{c}u_1(x_0) \\ u_1^{(1)}(x_0) \\ u_1^{(2)}(x_0)\\ \vdots \\ u_1^{(n-1)}(x_0)\end{array}\right]+\cdots+a_n\left[\begin{array}{c}u_n(x_0) \\ u_n^{(1)}(x_0) \\ u_n^{(2)}(x_0)\\ \vdots \\ u_1^{(n-1)}(x_0)\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\\ \vdots\\ 0\end{array}\right]
$$
Therefore $u = a_1 u_1+\cdots+a_n u_n$ satisfies
$$
                    u(x_0)=u^{(1)}(x_0)=\cdots=u^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0.
$$
By uniqueness of solutions, any such $u$ must be identically $0$. So the Wronskian is $0$ at some $x_0$ iff the set of solutions $\{ u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n \}$ is a linearly-dependent set.